# My Flutter application got crashed on Qr scan in Flutter version 3.16.5

Tags: android, flutter, crash, flutter-qrcode

[image: Error message screenshot]

i am using qr_code_scanner: ^1.0.1
Flutter version 3.16.5

on scan any QR code my application got crashed,previously i used flutter version 3.1.1,but now i have to upgrade my flutter version for another project,
Please Help to encounter this issue.